# twisted reactor: priority and insights

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

Two simple questions about twisted reactor:

1. Is there a way to explicitly assign a priority while scheduling a task ?
2. Is it possible to inspect the reactor in order to list all the pending tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The reactor does not implement priority-based scheduling; it just runs events in whatever order they happen to come back from your multiplexing/timing mechanism, depending on the particular reactor implementation (it's slightly different for the different ones).

Implementing a scheduling or fair queueing API in the reactor would be an awesome addition, but it would be a non-trivial amount of work.